# In gmail, when I block messages from a certain sender, only future messages are blocked

Tags: gmail

When I block messages from a certain mail address in gmail, I get a message that future messages from that sender will be marked as spam.

But how to mark those messages already received as spam? Why would I be interested in keeping those?

Comment: "Why would you be interested"? Maybe you want to take some action against the sender and use those messages as evidence. The  "oh, I thought you weren't going to need those" approach to data storage has its drawbacks.

Comment: That would be a totally powerless action, wouldn´t it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mark those messages already received as spam. But if you did for any reason, just move it to Inbox (not spam) and block it again. Plus Gmail deletes spam messages after 30 days, so don't worry about it.